# How to fetch users by rating with mysql query? (Top Rated)

Tags: sql, mysql

There is a query I've just made

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM users 
INNER JOIN ratings ON ratings.rateable=users.id 
  ORDER BY SUM(ratings.rating)/COUNT(ratings.rating)
```

But, it doesn't work, I just get one person in result, although there are 3 people in ratings table! I'm using php 5.

I think sum(), count() doesn't work at all!
Please, help!! Cause I can't understand how to build TOP RATED system.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output from `DESCRIBE RATINGS` and `DESCRIBE USERS`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hunch, but `ratings.rateable` smells like a bit to me. Any chance the one result has users.id 1?

Is `ratings.rateable` really the foreign key to `users.id`?

Comment: yes, I've checked, ratings.rateable really the foreign key to users.id

Comment: Take out the `ORDER BY` clause to isolate the problem.

Comment: Are the 3 people in the ratings table unique? That is, does each of the 3 records in the ratings table have a different value in the `rateable` column?

Comment: I get 5 people avatars. At all There are 3 people in ratings table, but 2 of them have 2 ratings, so I get 5 people avatars

Comment: No, There are five records in table ratings, one record is unique

Comment: 5 records, 1 unique. I don't understand why in the question it says "there are 3 people in ratings table!"

Comment: What are the 5 values for the `rateable` column in the `ratings` table?

Comment: 2
3
1
1
3

End of rateable column

Comment: Did you try the query without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Clearly then your `ORDER BY` clause is the problem, which, now that I look at it, should have been obvious all along. I assume you are trying to order by average rating?

Comment: Let's start by wrapping the Sum/Count clause in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because I can't see all of your stuff....but my guess is in the ' ON ratings.rateable=users.id ' part of your SQL.  Are you storing the users.id field value in the rateable column in your ratings table?